# SKEmitterNode: modify properties like velocity and angle for individual particles?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skemitternode

The SKEmitterNode in SpriteKit lets you change particle properties, but it's not clear how you change properties for specific particles.

For instance, if we want particles to radiate in a circle shape, it seems we need to dictate the angle and speed for each particle -- not specify values for particles as a group.

Is this possible?

Put another way, is it possible to use the SKEmitterNode to create animations like the one from this video at the 0:22 mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYy2G0lVTAM

Comment: The only that comes to my mind is to create multiple particle systems with different properties and add them to the same node.

Comment: You have no control over individual particles, you can only determine what they are like when they are born.  (think of it like a test-tube baby, you can specify what genes you want the baby to have, but after that, the baby will grow however it feels like)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ok that's what it seems like, thanks for the confirmation. could you please post as an answer so you can get credit?

Comment: You can create that animation like a firework without control single particle

Comment: @SimonePistecchia can you explain how as an answer? thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot let me to come back to home and I'll show you. In the middle time, see this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwFFZThm6ME fire water fireworks, stars ande cloud were built with particles

Comment: @SimonePistecchia thanks! which animations are you referring to? there are a lot? could you kindly provide the timestamps for the animations? thanks again.

Comment: yes, i'll do it ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no control over individual particles, you can only determine what they are like when they are born. (think of it like a test-tube baby, you can specify what genes you want the baby to have, but after that, the baby will grow however it feels like)

At some point apple may get SKActions working on the particles so that you can do this kind of stuff, but I wouldn't hold my breath on it working anytime soon, they seem to have no care in the SpriteKit platform, just introducing new broken things to get people excited.  ( I am cringing on how buggy ARKit will be)

Comment: scary how fast you are :)

Comment: when Im not working at my job I am working on my game, so I spend almost 16 hours a day on a computer

Comment: since you're here already, do you happen to know how to make sprites "twinkle" like at the 0:11 mark of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYy2G0lVTAM. been trying to use `colorize` to change colors, but doesn't seem to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I would use SKShaders (I don't know how to use them, my partner does that stuff,) so I would try and find some tutorials on that

Comment: or the more dangerous approach, an emitter of emitters LOL

Answer (score 2):

you can do:

[image]

The image is a little star.
setting:
[image]

Comment: what's btw consulting?